# Как убрать виджет из макета

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qstackedwidget, parent

У меня есть приложение, в котором есть **`4`** страницы и на **`1`**-ой странице находится календарь и виджет с погодой, который после нажатия кнопки обрезается, так как находится в макете.

Я хочу **`убрать виджет с погодой из макета`**, однако не знаю как это правильно сделать.

---

---

До нажатия на кнопку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

После нажатия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Как должно быть**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

Вот сам код: (часть кода с погодой находится на 143 строке кода)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.Qt import *
from ext import *
from main import App                              # +++ 
from part_1 import Main

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(845,535))
#        
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
# Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)
        
        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
                
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('солнышко.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('папочка.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)
           
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))

        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
#1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)

        self.main = App()

        self.main.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 154))
        self.main.w_root.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.main.w_root, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.main.w_root.setWindowFlag(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: green; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

# page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
     
        self.gg = Main()
        
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               

        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.gg)

        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')
     
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
# verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
# verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
  
# календарь
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
      
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12,))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ivapop не очень понятно что вы хотите получить в итоге. Вы хотите перекрыть календарь виджетом погоды?. тогда зачем вам такой календарь? Объясните пожалуйста лучше и покажите/нарисуйте вид вашего окна, которое вы хотите получить.

Comment: Когда выдвигается виджет с погодой, кнопка также выдвигается, и если ее нажать после выдвижения виджета, то он свернется и будет выглядеть как на 1 картинке.

Comment: ответьте мне,  пожалуйста, почему вы не хотите использовать макет - `QHBoxLayout` и убрать `min-width: 800px; max-width: 800px;` в вашем `StyleSheet`? а также постарайтесь ответить на вопросы из первого комментария.

Comment: @S.Nick Я поправил вопрос и указал, как виджет с погодой должен выглядеть.

Comment: И я не хочу использовать QHBoxLayout, т.к мне больше нравится нынешний внешний вид приложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предисловие:

- я убрал некоторые импорты, который неизвестны  и
  не влияют на суть вопроса. Это виджет для четвертой страницы и еще что-то.
- я переместил виджет календарь, в то место, где он должен находится.
- я заменил виджет для загрузки на первую страницу своим,
  так как ваш виджет не могу воспроизвести.
- поменяйте картинки на свои.

По сути заданного вопроса:

- как убрать виджет из макета - не надо его туда помещать.
- чтобы нарисовать один виджет поверх другого надо
  для верхнего виджета установить родителя (нижний виджет)

```
    self.main = App()

    self.main.setParent(self.page_1)
```

- кнопка, о которой вы пишите, должна быть проверяемой

  `QPushButton.setCheckable(True)`
- для этой же кнопки вы должны привязать сигнал `clicked`
  к слоту (например `self.button_clicked`), в котором
  будите менять размеры верхнего виджета, если он не сворачивается у вас.

  `self.designer_button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)`
- в слоте `button_clicked` вы устанавливаете нужные вам размеры и
  регулирует размер виджета, чтобы он соответствовал его содержимому.

```
    def button_clicked(self):
        #print(f'{self.designer_button.isChecked()}')
        if self.designer_button.isChecked():
            self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 535))
            self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 535))
            self.label_image.show()
        else:
            self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
            self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
            self.label_image.hide()
        self.adjustSize()                                # !!! ВАЖНО
```

---

---

**q1302442.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PyQt5.Qt import *
# ? from ext import *

#from main import App                                        # +++ 
from q1302442_second import App                              # ---

# ? from part_1 import Main

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(845,535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        # Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)

        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('ball.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('lena-2.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
# 1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
# +++        
        self.label_1.setMinimumHeight(160)                              # +++
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)

# +++ календарь должен быть здесь
# календарь
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)

# +++
        self.main = App()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.main.setParent(self.page_1)  # Устанавливает родительский элемент виджета
        self.main.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
        self.main.move(455, 0)            # Это соответствует перемещению (QPoint(x, y)).
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        
#        self.main.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 154))
#        self.main.w_root.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
#        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.main.w_root, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
#        self.main.w_root.setWindowFlag(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
#        self.main.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 154))
#        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.main, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: green; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

# page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
     
#        self.gg = Main()                                           # раскомментируйте
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               
#        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.gg)                   # раскомментируйте
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')
       
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
        # verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        # verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12,))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1302442_second.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QApplication, QMainWindow


class AnimationShadowEffect(QGraphicsDropShadowEffect):
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimationShadowEffect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setColor(color)
        self.setOffset(0, 0)
        self.setBlurRadius(0)
        self._radius = 0
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setTargetObject(self)
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)            
        self.animation.setLoopCount(-1)             
        self.animation.setPropertyName(b'radius')
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0, 1)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0.5, 30)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(1, 1)

    def start(self):
        self.animation.start()

    def stop(self, r=0):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.radius = r

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, r):
        self._radius = r
        self.setBlurRadius(r)


class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    hover = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText("Button")
        self.setFixedSize(200, 70)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("enterEvent")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.hover.emit("leaveEvent")
        

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        self.resize(357, 205)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(41, 41, 62);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.label_image = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('Ok.png')
        self.label_image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label_image.hide()
        
        self.designer_button = PushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.designer_button.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                background-color: rgb(28, 28, 42);
                border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
                border-radius: 15px;
                color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
                font-family: Calibre, Helvetica Neue, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida           Grande sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 500;
            }
            QPushButton:hover { 
                background-color: rgb(16, 16, 24);
                color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
            }
            QPushButton:pressed { 
                background-color: rgb(6, 6, 8);
                color: rgb(41, 41, 62);
            }
        """)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)   
        self.layout.addWidget(
            self.label_image, 0, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(
            self.designer_button, 1, 1, 
                alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter |QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
            
        self.aniButton = AnimationShadowEffect(QtCore.Qt.white, self.designer_button)
        
        self.designer_button.hover.connect(self.button_hover)
        self.designer_button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.designer_button.setGraphicsEffect(self.aniButton)

    def button_hover(self, hover):
        if hover == "enterEvent":
            self.aniButton.start()
        elif hover == "leaveEvent":
            self.aniButton.stop()
            
    def button_clicked(self):
        #print(f'{self.designer_button.isChecked()}')
        if self.designer_button.isChecked():
            self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 535))
            self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 535))
            self.label_image.show()
        else:
            self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
            self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
            self.label_image.hide()
        self.adjustSize()                                # !!! ВАЖНО
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]